# How can I stop a server service in circus?

Tags: python, service, circusd

Does anybody know how to turn off services in circus? I'm able to start services by using this line

```
 cmd =  /sbin/service mysqld restart
```

but apparently when I turn off the watcher in circusctl the service is still running

```
 [root@devel1 bin]# service mysqld status
 mysqld (pid  7571) is running...
 [root@devel1 bin]# circusctl
 circusctl 0.11.1
 circusd-stats: active
 hello: active
 httpd: active
 mysql: active
 plugin:myplugin: active
 webapp: stopped
 (circusctl) stop mysql
 ok
 (circusctl)
 [root@devel1 bin]# service mysqld status
 mysqld (pid  8342) is running...
 [root@devel1 bin]#
```

here is my circus.ini file.

```
 [circus]
 statsd = True
 httpd_host = 127.0.0.1
 httpd_port = 8080
 endpoint = tcp://127.0.0.1:5555

 [watcher:webapp]
 cmd = bin/chaussette --fd $(circus.sockets.web)
 numprocesses = 3
 use_sockets = True

 [watcher:hello]
 cmd = php /home/joseph/php/helloworld.php --fd $(circus.sockets.web)
 numprocess = 2
 use_sockets = True
 stdout_stream.filename = /home/joseph/test.log

 [watcher:mysql]
 cmd =  /sbin/service mysqld restart
 numprocess = 1
 stdout_stream.filename = /tmp/circus.log

 [watcher:httpd]
 cmd =  /sbin/service httpd $(circus.env.shell)
 numprocess = 1
 stdout_stream.filename = /tmp/circus.log

 [socket:web]
 host = 127.0.0.1
 port = 8888
```

Comment: have you tried circusctl quit?. This(http://aameer.github.io/circus-as-an-alternative-to-supervisor/) may be of some help

Answer (score 0):

What you see is the result of `/sbin/service`, as that demonize `mysql` process.

If you want `circus` to manage the process then you need to handle the process **undaemonised** to `circus`.

Change the line to run the actual mysql process::

```
cmd =  /sbin/service mysqld restart
```